# Utilizar CASE dentro de un NOT IN en SQL SERVER 2012

Tags: sql-server

Tengo el siguiente `Query`:

```
SELECT *
FROM #TABLAS
WHERE PORTAFOLIO NOT IN (CASE WHEN ID_TRABAJADOR = 2750 THEN (5,10,15) ELSE 0 END)
```

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Si el trabajador es el 2750 necesito que no tome en cuenta los portafolios 5, 10 y 15 y para cualquier otro empleado que solo no tome en cuenta el portafolio 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que lo no es necesario el `CASE`. Lo puedes resolver así

```
SELECT *
FROM #TABLAS
WHERE (ID_TRABAJADOR = 2750 AND PORTAFOLIO NOT IN (5,10,15)) OR (ID_TRABAJADOR <> 2750 AND PORTAFOLIO <> 0);
```